# Why does Firebase show some weird errors, as I haven’t had any dot (`.`) related error?

Tags: node.js, firebase, cmd, google-cloud-functions

Why does Firebase show some weird errors? I haven’t had any dot (`.`) related error.

```sh
functions@ build E:\deepak\function\functions
tslint --project tsconfig.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc
```

> ```
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! functions@ build: `tslint --project tsconfig.json && ./node_modules/.bin/tsc`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are triying to run the command on CMD, it doesn't recognize the current path with (./) replace the slashes for backslashes or put the full path (on windows style with backslashes)for example:

tslint --project tsconfig.json && .\node_modules.bin\tsc

This is because windows uses backslash for the paths